# How to get body from a request?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using `play 2.8.x framework` as a backend and I need to get `POST` requests from clients. These requests have a JSON body like the following:

```
{
  "userId": "jjjjssss"
}
```

and I want to have the `Controller method` on the server-side looks like the following:

```
public Result getUser(String userId) {
   ...
   return ok();
}
```

or something like this:

```
public Result getUser(String jsonBody) {
   ...
   return ok();
}
```

How can I do it? 
Can the `play 2.8.x framework` pass the body of requests to the controller method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I understand what you're asking correctly you have to parse the request body in the controller method like this:

```
YourJsonClass theBody = request.body().parseJson(YourJsonClass.class)
```

This way the userId will have to be in YourJsonClass and the url path would be redundant.

More on this here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaJsonActions#Handling-a-JSON-request

Just make sure that your request is a POST request that has the Content-Type header set to

**application/json;charset=utf-8**

Comment: In this way I have to pass the all HttpRequest object as the method parameter instead of ```userId``` variable only.

Comment: That's the only way to get the request body. This is a very common pattern in Play!

Comment: Please bear in mind that the request param will be passed by Play! automatically. You will not have to pass anything yourself.